# Launching hyperlinks using non default Windows Viewer in ESRI Web Applications

Tags: python, javascript, image, arcgis-portal, hyperlink

We have developed a custom Python based image viewer, which we would like to deploy in Portal for ArcGIS for viewing hyperlinked images (through attribute tables). We can't use the native Windows Photo Viewer as it does not work with this specific image format.

At the moment, the default for the popup in web maps uses Windows Photo Viewer.

Is there a way to change this either in the hyperlink field directly, so that we can click on a feature and pass a field value (in this case file path) to a python script, or in the JS code of the web application?

Comment: I don't know if this will work but you can give it a try. What web server are you using? If it is IIS, how about you define a MIME type for the image format you have and then change the default program for it on the server. Any client (browser) accessing the hyperlinked image will be responsible for the rendering so I wonder how it will interpret the image type if windows photo viewer doesn't work with it. 

Can you share the image extension type?

Comment: @Don, the format is SEGY, which is a binary file containing seismic amplitude values held in 2D array of traces and depths. The Python viewer that we developed converts these values into pixels by assigning value range to colour scheme. I believe we are using IIS. Wouldn't the MIME workflow only set the default program for .py file?